# symfony should I create a new bundle or use appbundle

Tags: symfony

I am new to Symfony and have been watching a lot of tutorials on using this MVC. They all start (at least the ones I've seen) by saying your app should be in it's own bundle. When I start a new project it comes with AppBundle already there. Should I create a new bundle or use this one.

I realise that people to things differently and that symfony.com says that best practice is to use AppBundle but from what I can see the resources folder is outside of AppBundle instead of within the bundle in the case of creating a new one.

I hope I'm not being too cryptic in my question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It all comes down to how you want to structure your code. For smaller projects it makes sense to use AppBundle only - for larger projects it is easier to maintain when there is logical separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2/3 has a great documentation. There is a complete section that handle the topic of bundles.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

Take a look at the Cookbook there are a lot of great informations. For your question you can create so much Bundles you need. A bundle should be a complete topic of a function for example a "NewsletterBundle" which holds all your functions for a complete Newsletter section. You should find your own way with one eye on the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the @Stony's answer, and answer the title of your question, you can perfectly use the AppBundle.

It's a good example to start with Symfony.

It contains a first route that checks your configuration, uses the `Request` component, access to a config parameter and display a link to the [Create your first page with Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/page_creation.html) part of Symfony2 book, in a twig template.